# fastest way to load data to a pd.DataFrame using different formats (csv, json, avro)

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, avro

We are loading big amounts of data from `google bigquery` to `pandas dataframe` (to be consumed directly as a `pandas` and also to be consumed as a `xgbMatrix`).

BQ export formats are `CSV`, `JSON` and `AVRO`, our data has dates, integers, floats and strings, and is usually "wide" (many columns). Our first approach was import the data as CSV, but the parsing time is huge:

`(32 GB,126 files,CSV) -> 25 min`

parsing code:

```
def load_table_files_to_pandas(all_files, 
                           table_ref):

# load files to pandas
dict_dtype = {}
date_cols = []

client =  bigquery.Client() # create a bq client
table = client.get_table(table_ref)

for field in table.schema:
    pd_dtypes = {'string':'object',
                 'date':'object',
                 'float':'float64',
                 'integer':'float64'
                 }
    dict_dtype[field.name] = pd_dtypes[field.field_type.lower()]
    if field.field_type.lower()== 'date':
        date_cols.append(field.name)

print('start reading data')    
df_from_each_file = []
for f in all_files:
    # looping over files
    df_from_each_file.append(pd.read_csv(f, 
                                         dtype = dict_dtype, 
                                         parse_dates = date_cols))

    print('memory in use = {}'.format(psutil.virtual_memory().percent))

df = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
print('end reading data')
return df
```

Which format is a faster for parsing in `pandas`? `[Avro,CSV,JSON]`? Is there maybe a third one not considered?

**additional** 
we also tried with `dask|csv` directly from storage and from local disk, but the parsing time was almost the same.

Comment: Do you mind to write few lines of code about how you are parsing code? Regarding file format I'm quite happy with `.parquet`. You can read parquet with recent pandas versions or dask. You might keep in mind this [tweet](https://twitter.com/wesmckinn/status/1020327908160794624) from Wes McKinney

Comment: @user32185 added ;)

Comment: @user32185 Actually, there a so many issues currently with parquet files of size > 2GB in Python - regardless of the lib you use being it either pyarrow or fastparquet. You will run into limitations: not all files you create with spark can be read with ANY of the currently available libs.

Answer (score 3):

use pandas [`pandas.read_gbq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_gbq.html) it is specifically designed for `google bigquery`.

you may instead want to export it in chunks and then build a `dask` pipeline to parse it and load it in parallel (and in a larger then ram manner).

according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34687663/9253013)

> BigQuery is able to export data in chunks - and you can request as many chunks as workers you have.

if the data is not nested and repeated (note the [Export limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data)) you may export to `csv` and use `dask`s [`read_csv`](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv) method to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with such large files I would use Spark with Parquet format. This way you can scale up your reads and computations. Pandas is not made for such large files.