# Facing Memory Error while reading the file from google bigquery

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to read 1.8 M rows of data from google bigquery in python but facing the memory error issue. as I am using pandas_gbq for this.

```
import pandas_gbq as pgq


a= pgq.read_gbq(viewsql, project_id = env_config['projectid'], private_key = 
   env_config['service_account_key_file']+".json")
```

Comment: you can read chunks in such cases. df = pd.read_csv('filename',chunksize=(any number of chunk you wan eg: 5000)

Comment: @anky_91 can we do the same for the Bigquery table

Comment: i think so. you can look it up in the web or this link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685577/how-to-best-process-large-query-results-written-to-intermediate-table-in-app-eng